# Kendo Grid Detail Template Grid Not Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The grid in my detail template is not binding the data properly. If I expand one by one from top to bottom, it only binds the data for the first row and the grid inside all other rows are empty. If I expand them from bottom to top, it binds the data properly for all the rows. Any idea why it's doing this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmailInvitationViewModel>()
    .Name("EmailInviteeGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.EmailInviteID).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(e => e.InvitationDate).Title("Invited On").Hidden(false);
        columns.Bound(e => e.ClassDetails)
            .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains")))
            .Title("Class Details");
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllInvitedEvents", "Controller", new { Model.EventID }))
    )
)
 
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmailInvitationViewModel>()
        .Name("grid_#=EmailInviteID#") 
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.GridInviteeEmail);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllInviteeEmailsByEvent", "DataSource", new { EventID = "#=EventID#", EmailInviteID = "#=EmailInviteID#" }))
        )
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
```

Comment: I've seen that happen when the name of the subgrid is not unique. Your code looks correct, but check the name of the subgrid and make sure it renders a different name for each master row.

Comment: @SteveGreene You are absolutely correct! Thanks!!!!